# Download and get HTML code from a website

Tags: parsing, web, rust

I need to download HTML code from some web page. What is the best way to approach this task? As I understand there are very few working web frameworks for Rust right now and hyper is the one most people use? But after searching it's documentation I couldn't find a way. The closest I got is this

```
extern crate hyper;

use hyper::Client;

fn main() {
    let client = Client::new();
    let res = client.get("http://www.bloomberg.com/")
        .send()
        .unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

But it returns `Response`, which doesn't seem to contain any code from HTML body.

Comment: a quick google search revealed this:
https://github.com/chris-morgan/rust-http

Comment: I saw that, not sure how it's supposed to help me when it says that I shouldn't use that lib. And hyper, to which it links, like i wrote in OP, I cant figure out.

Comment: `rust-http` is very old and not really supported. `hyper` should indeed be used instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Note*: this answer is outdated!**

I don't have the time to update this with every hyper release. But please see my answer to a very related question: [How can I download a website's content into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52962233/2408867)

---

It's a bit hidden: The [`Response`](http://hyper.rs/hyper/hyper/client/response/struct.Response.html) type implements the trait `Read`. One method of `Read` is `read_to_string` which reads everything into the a `String`. That's a simple way you can get the body.

```
extern crate hyper;

use hyper::Client;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let client = Client::new();
    let mut res = client.get("http://www.bloomberg.com/")
        .send()
        .unwrap();
    let mut body = String::new();
    res.read_to_string(&mut body).expect("failed to read into string");
    println!("{}", body);
}
```

Currently Rustdoc (the HTML documentation of Rust) is a little bit misleading because Rust beginners think that trait implementations don't add any important functionality. This is not true, so better look out for it. However, the hyper documentation could be better...

Comment: Is this answer still valid or is it outdated? I'm getting `no method named read_to_string found for type hyper::Response`

Comment: @Keatinge I added a note to the answer. Sadly, it is outdated. Now (0.11) it looks like you have to call `body()` which returns something implementing the `Stream` trait. But I haven't used hyper for a while; this is only a guess.