# How can I download a website's content into a string?

Tags: rust

I would simply like to download a website and put its contents into a `String`.

Similar to how this is done in C#:

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
string ex = c.DownloadString("http://url.com");
```

Comment: https://github.com/hyperium/hyper

Comment: Hi Laz, welcome to StackOverflow! Since no one of the downvoters commented, let me explain what are probably the reasons for the downvotes. Most importantly, your question sounds like you didn't even google or did anything else to find an answer yourself. People here on SO don't like that. Furthermore, some people might think you are asking for a library recommendation, because *they* know that there is no HTTP stuff in Rust's standard library. Personally, I disagree with at least the close votes. I still thought the question was worth answering. Anytime, have a nice time on SO!

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Understandable. My apologies.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Rust has **no HTTP functionality in the standard library**, so you probably want to use another crate (library) to handle HTTP stuff for you. There are several different crates for this purpose.

---

#### [`reqwest`](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest): "higher level HTTP client library"

You need to enable the `blocking` feature to use the non-`async` API.

```rust
let body = reqwest::blocking::get("http://url.com")?.text()?;
```

#### [`ureq`](https://crates.io/crates/ureq): "Minimal HTTP request library"

```rust
let body = ureq::get("http://url.com").call()?.into_string()?
```

#### [`isahc`](https://crates.io/crates/isahc): "The practical HTTP client that is fun to use."

```rust
let mut response = isahc::get("https://example.org")?;
let body = response.text()?;
```

#### [`curl`](https://crates.io/crates/curl): "Rust bindings to libcurl for making HTTP requests"

```
use curl::easy::Easy;

// First write everything into a `Vec<u8>`
let mut data = Vec::new();
let mut handle = Easy::new();
handle.url("http://url.com").unwrap();
{
    let mut transfer = handle.transfer();
    transfer.write_function(|new_data| {
        data.extend_from_slice(new_data);
        Ok(new_data.len())
    }).unwrap();
    transfer.perform().unwrap();
}

// Convert it to `String`
let body = String::from_utf8(data).expect("body is not valid UTF8!");
```

#### [`hyper`](https://crates.io/crates/hyper)?

Hyper is a very popular HTTP library, but it's rather low-level. This makes it usually too hard/verbose to use for small scripts. However, if you want to write a HTTP server, Hyper sure is the way to go (that's why Hyper is used by most Rust Web Frameworks).

#### Many others!

I couldn't list all available libraries in this answer. So feel free to search crates.io for more crates that could help you.